# Difference between ilookup and ilookup5 in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

There are two functions in fs/inode.c:

1. `struct inode *ilookup5(struct super_block *sb, unsigned long hashval, int (*test)(struct inode *, void *), void *data)`
2. `struct inode *ilookup(struct super_block *sb, unsigned long ino)`

This is part of comment of `ilookup5`:

> This is a generalized version of ilookup() for file systems where the inode number is not sufficient for unique identification of an inode.

This is quoted from *Professional Linux Architecture*

> There are, however, filesystems in which there is no guarantee that inodes can be identified by reference to their number and associated superblock. In this situation, additional elements must be scanned (using filesystem-specific methods); ilookup5 is provided
> as a front end for this purpose. Currently, the function is not in widespread use except for sysfs and some rarely used filesystems
> like OCFS2, but external code for more esoteric filesystems is able to access it.

So under what circumstances is inode number unable to uniquely identify an inode?

Comment: Well, in the case the particular FS does not have unique inode numbers under the same superblock.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli That's exactly what I can't understand. Why unique inode numbers can be insufficient? I mean, inode number should be as large as 2^32 or ^64, it is much bigger than what a real filesystem needs.

Comment: Why must they be sufficient in the first place? I could invent a filesystem for which inode numbers are not unique just because I want to. Since some of those filesystems already exist, Linux made the choice to support them through different internal APIs such as `ilookup5()`.